# Producer Partition Count override not effective

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Interpreting this - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_producer_properties

my understanding is that, if the partitionCount override is less than the actual number of partitions on an existing kafka topic, then the producer should use the actual number of partitions rather than the override value. My experience is that the producer uses the partitionCount value regardless of how many partitions ( > partitionCount ) are actually configured on the kafka topic.

Ideally, I would like the producer to read the number of partitions on a pre-configured topic from kafka and write messages across all available partitions.

- Spring-Cloud version: Finchley.RELEASE
- Kafka Broker version : 1.0.0

application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        contentType: application/json
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers:
          - ${KAFKA_HOST}:${KAFKA_PORT}
          auto-create-topics: false
      bindings:
        input-channel:
          destination: input-topic
          contentType: application/json
          group: input-group
        output-channel:
          destination: output-topic
          contentType: application/json
          producer:
            partition-count: 2
            partition-key-expression: payload['Id']
```

So, I am expecting that if the output topic is already configured with 6 partitions, the producer will recognise this and write to all of those. Could someone please verify my interpretation above? Or point out what I am missing to get the desired functionality?

Comment: There was a recent commit that fixed this issue in spring-cloud-stream core and the kafka binder. Can you try this on a recent snapshot and see if this issue is addressed?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @sobychacko. I'll try that.

Comment: @sobychacko - took me a while to get maven dependencies right for snapshot build, but have built with Fishtown.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and can confirm that messages are distributed across all 6 available partitions when partition-count property is set to 2, so looks like the issue is addressed. Any idea which release will contain this fix?

Comment: Fishtown is scheduled to have an M2 release next week and that release will have this fix. RC1 is scheduled to go sometime in September and GA will follow once Spring Boot goes GA with 2.1.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know.